# How to get a Firestore document ID based on its content?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, document

I am trying to get a way to delete firestore document by a click event.

here is what i have so far. `x` is the document id i get from firestore. But how to get the ID change dynamically based on the content show in the page? SO that user can delete the content they wanted.

```
var deleteContent = document.getElementById('delete');
deleteContent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // get current document ID

    x = 'poOjcQce2iiKzp2FaFVA'
    var getId = db.collection("checkin").doc(x);

    getId.delete().then(function() {
        console.log(" successfully deleted!");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Firestore allows you to [perform simple and compounded queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). Essentially, you can provide a condition in the `db.collection(<COLLECTION>).where()` clause which will filter all documents that match that certain condition.

For illustrative purposes, suppose documents in the `a` collection follow the following structure: `{ id, '123', name: 'test', color: 'red' }`. If you want to get all documents with the color red, you can simply call `db.collection('a').where('color', '==', 'red')`, which you can then iterate into to process each document that matches that condition.

Moreover, in your specific case, suppose your document structure is `{ id, content }`you can try something like this:

```js
var deleteContent = document.getElementById('delete');
deleteContent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // get current document ID
    let docToDelete = db.collection("checkin").where('content', '==', 'CONTENT_GOES_HERE')

    x = docToDelete.id;
    var getId = db.collection("checkin").doc(x);

    getId.delete().then(function() {
        console.log(" successfully deleted!");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });

});
```

However, a much simpler way would be to store the document id somewhere within your application whenever a specific document is read, local storage or session storage for instance. As such, you can refer to the document id whenever you need. For example, suppose that you fetch all of a user's documents in an onLoad event handler --- suppose that you have HTML elements with the id 'content1', 'content2', 'content3', etc. and that it is where the contents of your documents are shown. You can try something like this:

```js
let userId = 123;

[...].onload = () => {
  // Get all of the documents belonging to this user
  let i = 0;
  let docs = [];
  let documents = db.collection('posts').where('userId', '==', userId);
  documents.forEach(doc => {
    document.getElementById(`content${i}`).innerHTML = JSON.stringify(doc.data()); // Just stringifying to be certain
    /**
     * Extra step to add the document id in the sessionStorage so that we can refer to it later
     */
     htmlId = 'content' + i;
     sessionStorage.setItem(htmlID, doc.id );
  })

}
```

In doing so, you can simply refer to the document id like such `sessionStorage.getItem('content2')`.

Note that in any of the examples I listed, there is heavy preparation that needs to be done in order for this to be as smooth sailing as possible. However, wouldn't you agree that a programmer merely is a person that spends hours on things that takes minutes for the sake of making it easier in subsequent uses? :)

Comment: No worries, best of luck!